# JAVA jar obfuscation not working NoClassDefError

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I have a jar file example.jar having packages

```
org.personal.example.*
org.personal.myexample.*
```

and classes in it. The jar file is is named example.jar and signed it using self certificate.
I am producing output as example_obfu.jar and trying to load it from HTML but is says noClassDef found error. By the way it is an Applet.

html code is

```
<APPLET ARCHIVE="example_obfu.jar" CODE="org/personal/example/MainApplet.class" WIDTH=900 HEIGHT=300  mayscript="mayscript">
```

My configuration file is

```
-injars example.jar
-outjars example_obfu.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar;<java.home>/lib/plugin.jar;<java.home>/lib/jce.jar;<java.home>/lib/ext/jaccess.jar;<java.home>/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar;<java.home>/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
-dontoptimize
-printmapping myprint.txt
-keep public class org.personal.example.* extends javax.swing.JApplet{}
#-keep public class org.personal.example.** {public private protected *;} (I tried this as well)
```

Comment: Have you checked the class is actually present in the *obfu jar? Also, you can extract the classfile and run `javap <classfile>` to see the class definition.

Comment: Maybe you could use a different obfuscator? This one doesn't seem to be working.